# R language Error in xy.coords(x, y)

Tags: r

I am following the tutorial (it is my first time with R) on how vizualise connections R http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/

I made some small changes to display specific data but I am having some problems when executing the last step of plotting lines() functions.

I get the following error when executing the below c

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

The information I am passing to plot is the following

```
> airports
    iata                                      country        lat        long
1     AD                                      Andorra  42.546245    1.601554
2     AE                         United Arab Emirates  23.424076   53.847818

>flights
  AIRLINE AIRLINE1 AIRPORT CNT
1    AK02       NZ      AR 130
2    AS01       GB      AE 257
```

The code I am trying to execute is the below

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(XLConnect)               # load XLConnect package 

wk1 = loadWorkbook("C:/Users/cacoteh/AppData/Local/NoBackup/flights.xlsx") 
wk2 = loadWorkbook("C:/Users/cacoteh/AppData/Local/NoBackup/airports.xlsx") 

flights = readWorksheet(wk1, sheet="flights")
airports = readWorksheet(wk2, sheet="airports")

# Unique carriers
carriers <- unique(flights[1])

# Color
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#333333", "white", "#1292db"))
colors <- pal(100)

pdf(paste("carrier.pdf", sep=""), width=11, height=7)
map("world", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="#f5f5dc", lwd=0.05)
maxcnt <- max(flights["CNT"])
for (j in 1:nrow(flights) ) {
  air1 <- flights[j,"AIRLINE1"]
  for (k in 1: nrow(airports) ) { 
    if ( airports[k,1] == air1 ) {
      lat1 <- airports[k,3]
      lon1 <- airports[k,4]
    }
  }
  air2 <- flights[j,"AIRPORT"]
  for (k in 1: nrow(airports) ) { 
    if ( airports[k,1] == air2 ) {
      lat2 <- airports[k,3]
      lon2 <- airports[k,4]
    }
  }

  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), n=100, addStartEnd=TRUE, breakAtDateLine=TRUE)
  colindex <- round( ( flights[j,4] / maxcnt )* length(colors) )
  lines(inter, col="black", lwd=0.8)
    }

dev.off()
```

The output of the gcIntermediate (inter) is the following :

```
> inter
[[1]]
          lon       lat
[1,] 174.8860 -40.90056
[2,] 175.6352 -41.51760
[3,] 176.3988 -42.12968
[4,] 177.1773 -42.73661
[5,] 177.9710 -43.33816
[6,] 178.7806 -43.93411
[7,] 180.0000 -44.52423

[[2]]
             lon       lat
 [1,] -180.00000 -45.10827
 [2,] -178.69075 -45.68599
 [3,] -177.81287 -46.25713
 [4,] -176.91662 -46.82140
```

Not sure where exactly there is the mistake. If someone would be able to give me an help I would appreciated.

Thank you, 
Hugo

Comment: As the error says, `inter` is a list. You will need to make it into a flat table or devise your own function that will handle plotting a list (of matrices). You can flatten the list using `do.call("rbind", inter)`.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post the error *when* it occurs so we don't have to hunt thru your code for the offending line.

Comment: I sorry not used to coding. The error occurs when the function lines(inter, col="black", lwd=0.8) is invoked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
#lines(inter,col="#bb4cd4",lwd=1) only for the result is matrix but not list
#so you can do it like this:
if(is.matrix(inter))
lines(inter,col="#bb4cd4",lwd=1)
else {
lines(inter[[1]],col="#bb4cd4",lwd=1);
lines(inter[[2]],col="#bb4cd4",lwd=1)
}
```